# Features - Custom User Fields Not Available after Import

Tags: features

I have two Drupal sites.

On Site1, I created 4 custom text fields for the User Profile. I created a Feature that included these fields. I didn't see an area where I could export the settings for Custom User fields, so I searched for their respective machine names and added them.

[image]

On site #2, I added the feature and the fields now appear to be imported.

[image]

Despite this, when going to Configuration > People > Account settings, going to "Add existing field" does not list the newly imported fields to that list. They also are not available as "Existing Fields" when modifying a Content Type.

[image]

On top of that, when attempting to create a field with the same machine name, it states that it is already taken.

[image]

It seems the Features has indeed imported the desired fields but they are for some reason inaccessible.

How can this be fixed?

Comment: You forget to export the field instances. Field instances is the instance of field base which attached to the entity type and bundle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution**

You have to add the corresponding field instances in feature as well. The field instance name should be in this format:

`[entity_type]-[bundle]-[field_name]`

In your case, they should be:

- `user-user-field_first_name`
- `user-user-field_last_name`
- `user-user-field_title`
- `user-user-field_email`

---

**Sub Question 1**

> Despite this, when going to Configuration > People > Account settings, going to "Add existing field" does not list the newly imported fields to that list. They also are not available as "Existing Fields" when modifying a Content Type.

**Answer**

You cannot find existing fields because there is no field instance attached on the field base. Drupal won't be able to load those field base without field instance.

---

**Sub Question 2**

> On top of that, when attempting to create a field with the same machine name, it states that it is already taken.

**Answer**

The field base is stored in database and also the table is created. So Drupal will stop you from recreation.

Comment: Great answer! +1 and marked as solution. Thank you for your clear and concise explanation! I learned something new about Features today.